# How to automatically find specific texts and format them into small caps in Word using macros?

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, ms-office

Let's say if I want to find all the texts, which appear behind the '-' in a table, in a document and format them all into small caps. See the example below.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unS3.png)
I want to change the 'pl', 'loc', 'prog', 'npst', 'adjl' in these two sentences into to small caps like Figure 1 and there are loads of this kind of situation.
Is there a way I can do that?
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is426.png)

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Make an attempt yourself, and ask a question once you encounter a problem in your code

Answer (score 0):

Finding and replacing is exposed by the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find) and [Replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.replacement) objects. The `Find` object is available from the `Selection` object and the `Range` object. The find action differs slightly depending upon whether you access the `Find` object from the `Selection` object or the `Range` object. For example, the following code removes the bold formatting:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find 
 .ClearFormatting 
 .Font.Bold = True 
 With .Replacement 
 .ClearFormatting 
 .Font.Bold = False 
 End With 
 .Execute FindText:="", ReplaceWith:="", _ 
 Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll 
End With
```

Read more about that in the [Finding and Replacing Text or Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Customizing-Word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting) article.